# Speedometer - Cable to digital modification

Tags: speedometer, custom, vehicle-speed-sensor

I have a custom vehicle that uses 1972 1600cc VW parts and has the cable driven speedometer in MPH.
I was curious if there is a reliable product that I can use to convert from anolog to digital to allow for smaller gauges/custom clusters.

Comment: You want us to research a suitable product?

Comment: Not research, but information on a unit that someone may have had installed in a professional environment. There's one I found that might work but holds no engineering testing certification so it makes me cautious to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Electronic speedometers typically pickup a signal from an electromagnetic pickup which takes a signal from a magnet attached to the output of the final drive.  It is possible to adapt certain gearboxes which provide a cable drive to use this type of pickup [such as this](https://www.burtonpower.com/revotec-electronic-speedo-adaptor-ford-gearbox-revt9-a.html) or you could fit ABS rings and take a feed from the wheel speed sensor.  Effectively, all you need is an electrical "pulse" and a speedometer capable of being calibrated to this signal.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a GPS Speedometer. Google it and you will find lots of options.

Comment: Check if a GPS speedometer is road legal in your country. (The UK legal situation is a bit silly - they are illegal since they don't work in all situations (e.g. in tunnels) but the speedo is not checked as part of the annual MOT vehicle test!)

Comment: GPS is not ideal, I currently use my GPS as a speedometer beside the anolog one to make sure my speed is accurate. Too many red light/speed traps where I'm from to loose signal and try to match crowd speed.